# Changes made to DOM during Promise.catch disappear

Tags: javascript, css, dom, dynamic, promise

I created a promise to grab data from my server, which works perfectly when there is a network connection.

I added a .catch() in order to display a DOM element if the server is unavailable. When fired, the .catch() works and the DOM element is displayed but it disappears after 2 seconds.

I tried adding the DOM element within the .catch(). I also tried putting the DOM addition in an external function and calling it. I also tried to pass the external function into the reject() function. Nothing has worked.

---Style Sheet---

> ```
>    #notice {
>        width: 100vw;
>        height: 100vh;
>        opacity: 0;
>        animation: fade-in 2s;
>        background-color:white;
>        z-index: 60;
>        display:flex;
>        align-items: center;
>        text-align: center;
>    }
>
>    #notice h1 {
>        font-size: 10vh;
>        font-family: 'Verdana';
>        color: black;
>    }
>
>    #notice * {
>        position: static;
>    }
> ```

---Javascript---

> ```
> getSolvedDeck = () => {
>   let failed = false;
>   new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
>      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
>      xhr.open('GET',
>               "https://mrlesbomar.com/solitaire/cgi-bin/get_solved_deck.php");
>      xhr.onload = () =>{
>         if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
>            resolve(xhr.response);
>         } else {
>            reject(xhr.statusText);
>         }
>      }
>      xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
>      xhr.send();
>   }).then(stuff=>{
>      console.log('Awesomeness');
>   }).catch(error=>{
>      //Create status screen
>      let notice = document.createElement('div');
>      notice.id = 'notice';
>      notice.innerHTML = '<h1>Error Message</h1><br/>';
>      document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].appendChild(notice);
>   });
> }
> ```

Expected Result: Upon Promise error the Screen fills with the appended DOM object and remains until the user takes action. Giving the user an opportunity to read the message.

Actual Results: The DOM object is appended to the `<main>`, fills the screen and presents the message, but disappears within 2 seconds.

Question: How can I make the actions taken in the .catch() persist?

Comment: I forgot to add the keyframes to the style sheet: `@keyframes fade-in{0%{opacity:0;}100%{opacity: 1;}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element persists, it's the css that's causing it to disappear. The animation runs once, stops, and we're back to opacity: 0. Will happen even with no JS at all:

```
<div id="notice"></div>
```

```
#notice {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: blue;
  animation: fade-in 2s;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMNaMv?&editable=true

To make the #notice stay on the screen, add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to its styles.

Comment: Thank You. That worked perfectly, I spent 2 hours looking for the solution. I used the same animation/css properties for another notice in the same application and didn't have this issue. Didn't even think to question the CSS.